# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'labels_'

Tags: python, error-handling, attributes

When I execute this code I get the following error:

> > > AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'labels_'

I understand that this message is triggered by the method:
clusterWithFewestSamples

by lines like:

minSamples = len(model.labels_)

Any hint on what's wrong or what's lacking?

Many thanks in advance.

Jordi

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')


def model(self, num):
    return

def showandtell(title=None):
    if title != None: plt.savefig(title + ".png", bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
    plt.show()
    exit()

def clusterInfo(model):
    print "Cluster Analysis Inertia: ", model.inertia_  
    print '------------------------------------------'
    for i in range(len(model.cluster_centers_)):
      print "\n  Cluster ", i
      print "    Centroid ", model.cluster_centers_[i]
      print "    #Samples ", (model.labels_==i).sum() # NumPy Power

def clusterWithFewestSamples(model):
    minSamples = len(model.labels_)
    minCluster = 0
    for i in range(len(model.cluster_centers_)):
        if minSamples > (model.labels_==i).sum():
            minCluster = i
            minSamples = (model.labels_==i).sum()
        print "\n Cluster With Fewest Samples: ", minCluster
    return (model.labels_==minCluster)

def doKMeans(data, clusters=0):
    df_user1 = data.loc[:, ['TowerLon', 'TowerLat']]
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=clusters)
    kmeans.fit(df_user1)
    labels = kmeans.predict(df_user1)
    centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    ax.scatter(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1], marker='x', c='red', alpha=0.5, linewidths=3, s=169)
    print centroids
    return model

df = pd.read_csv('Datasets/CDR.csv')
df.CallDate = pd.to_datetime(df.CallDate, errors='coerce')
df.CallTime = pd.to_timedelta(df.CallTime, errors='coerce')

PhoneList = df["In"].unique()

print "\n\nExamining person: ", 0

user1 = df[df.In == PhoneList[0]]
user1 = user1[(user1.DOW != 'Sat') & (user1.DOW != 'Sun')]
user1 = user1[(user1.CallTime > '09:00:00') | (user1.CallTime < '17:00:00')]

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(user1.TowerLon,user1.TowerLat, c='g', marker='o', alpha=0.2)
ax.set_title('Weekday Calls (>7:306am or <17p)')

model = doKMeans(user1, 2)

midWayClusterIndices = clusterWithFewestSamples(model)
midWaySamples = user1[midWayClusterIndices]
print " Its Waypoint Time: ", midWaySamples.CallTime.mean()

ax.scatter(model.cluster_centers_[:,1], model.cluster_centers_[:,0], s=169, c='r', marker='x', alpha=0.8, linewidths=2)

showandtell('Weekday Calls Centroids')
```

Comment: What is a ```model```?

Comment: [Catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and in the except suite inspect ```model``` - what [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) is it, does it [have a ```labels_``` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr), [what attributes does it have](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)?

Comment: is the indentation of line `print "    #Samples ", (model.labels_==i).sum() # NumPy Power` in `def clusterInfo(model)` right ?

Comment: Where does ```model``` come from?

Comment: The indentation was mistaken in the pasted code (but ok in the actual python code). Just edited.

Comment: model is in fact "doKMeans(user1, 2)" in line: model = doKMeans(user1, 2). I forgot also to paste the def at the beginning of the code. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why do you expect ```model``` to have a ```labels_``` attribute.

Comment: You are right. In fact it's not "model" that should have the attribute. I had explained (hopefully) better in a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `model` come from?

```
def doKMeans(data, clusters=0):
    ...
    return model

model = doKMeans(user1, 2)
```

In `doKMeans()` nothing ever gets assigned to `model`, I'm surprised it doesn't throw a NameError exception.  Maybe it should be

```
def doKMeans(data, clusters=0):
    ...
    return kmeans
```

An `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` object does have a `labels_` attribute.

---

You expect `model` to have a `labels_` attribute but you have defined `model` as a function that returns `None`

```
def model(self, num):
    return
```

When `doKMeans` is called, it returns the function named `model`

```
def doKMeans(data, clusters=0):
    ...
    return model
```

So the statement `model = doKMeans(user1, 2)` does nothing:

```
>>> def f(a,b):
    return
>>> f
<function f at 0x00000000034A9840>

>>> def g(a,b):
    return f

>>> f = g(1,2)
>>> f
<function f at 0x00000000034A9840>
```

Neither the function, `model`, or its return value, `None` have a `labels_` attribute.

Comment: I forgot to add 
    
    "def model(self, num): / 
         return"
 
at the beginning of the code (that is in the actual code, sorry about that). Before that addition I was getting an error message complaining about "model" as you imagined.

Comment: @JordiGalli - then what about this line - ```model = doKMeans(user1, 2)```  what does it do?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand that "model = doKMeans(user1, 3)" executes the doKMeans module with those parameters. Originally the "def model(self): return" wasn't there, but I got an error about global name model not being defined, so I added that and the error disappeared. Perhaps I should have added something to the return? When debugging it seems that the error arises after "midWayClusterIndices = clusterWithFewestSamples(model)" is executed. As you mention there is the message "--Return--
None". Not sure if this helps you understand what the problem could be. Thanks.